# CSS Menu - Making the sub menu drop down full width

Tags: jquery, html, css

Been trying for hours and not yet been successful in getting the sub menu full width to the window - i need it 100% width can anyone quickly lend a hand at all?

I have to override the CSS as cannot touch default so i added what i overridden already but need to add to it of course.

On the fiddle you need to adjust the output window so you dont get the mobile menu but the main desktop one.

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/eoc9213n/

DEFAULT CSS:

```
.ty-menu {
    .user-select(none);
    .clearfix();
}
.ty-menu__items {
    background: @menu;
    position: relative;
    .clearfix();
    .rounded_corners(6px);
}
.ty-menu__item {
    padding: 0px;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}
.ty-menu-rounded();

.ty-menu__item-active .ty-menu__item-link {
    background: darken(@menu, 5%)
}
.no-touch .ty-menu__item:hover .ty-menu__submenu-items,
.is-hover-menu .ty-menu__submenu-items {
    display: block;
}
.no-touch .ty-menu__item:hover .ty-menu__item-link,
.is-hover-menu .ty-menu__item-link,
.is-hover-menu.ty-menu__item-active .ty-menu__item-link {
    background: darken(@menu, 3%);
    color: white;
    text-shadow: none;
}
.ty-menu__item .ty-menu__item-link {
    color: @menu_links;
    position: relative;
    padding: 13px 20px;
    display: block;
    min-height: 46px;
    cursor: pointer;
    .box-sizing(border-box);
}

.ty-menu__item .ty-menu__item-link .ty-icon-down-micro {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 20px;
    right: 12px;
    top: 13px;
}
.ty-menu__submenu-items {
    min-width: 200px;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: white;
    z-index: 100;
    border: 1px solid darken(@menu, 4%);
    border-top: 0;
    padding: 15px 16px;
}
.ty-menu__submenu-items .ty-menu__submenu-item {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.ty-menu__submenu-items .ty-menu__submenu-link {
    color: @links;
}
.ty-menu__submenu-items .ty-top-mine__submenu-col {
    margin: 0px 10px 0px 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    min-width: 139px;
}
.ty-menu__submenu-items .ty-top-mine__submenu-col:last-child {
    margin-right: 1px;
}
.ty-menu__submenu-item-header {
    min-height: 25px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
}
.ty-menu__submenu-item-header .ty-menu__submenu-link {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: @links;
}
.ty-menu__submenu .ty-menu__submenu-items .ty-menu__submenu-item-active a {
    color: #FFF;
    background: @links;
    padding: 2px 6px;
}
.ty-menu__submenu-dropdown-bottom {
    display: block;
    background: #ECF0F1;
    margin: 0px -16px -15px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: right;
}
.ty-menu-rounded() when (@rounded_corners = true) {
    .ty-menu__item:nth-child(2) .ty-menu__item-link {
        border-top-left-radius: 6px;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
    }

    .ty-menu__submenu-items {
        border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
    }
}
```

CSS TO OVERRIDE DEFAULT:

```
.ty-menu {
    border-bottom: 0;
}
.ty-menu__items {
    background: none;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.ty-menu__item-active .ty-menu__item-link {
    background: none;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 18px 20px;
    min-height: 100%;
    padding: 14px 20px;
}
.ty-menu__item .ty-menu__item-link {
    color: #ffffff;
}
.no-touch .ty-menu__item:hover .ty-menu__item-link, .is-hover-menu .ty-menu__item-link, .is-hover-menu.ty-menu__item-active .ty-menu__item-link {
    background: #ffffff;
    color: #333;
}
.ty-menu__submenu-items, .ty-dropdown-box__content {
    border: 1px solid #dadada;
    border-top: 0;
}
.ty-dropdown-box__title.open {
    background: #dadada;
}
.ty-dropdown-box__title.open .ty-minicart-title {
    color: #333;
}
/* submenu */
 .ty-menu__submenu-to-right .ty-menu__submenu-items {
    right: auto;
}
.ty-menu__submenu .ty-menu__submenu {
    float: left;
    width: 240px;
}
.ty-menu__submenu .ty-menu__submenu li span {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #dadada;
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0 15px 10px;
    padding: 0 0 5px;
}
.ty-menu__submenu .ty-menu__submenu li a {
    padding: 4px 20px 5px 6px;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
/* Tablet */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 959px) {
}
/* Mobile */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    /* Social Count */
    .socialCount {
        text-align: center;
    }
    .cart-status {
        text-align: center;
        margin: 13px 0;
    }
    /* Make menu full width */
    .ty-menu__item.ty-menu__menu-btn.visible-phone, .ty-menu__items.cm-responsive-menu {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .ty-menu__submenu .ty-menu__submenu {
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
    }
    /* hide sub menu image */
    .ty-menu__submenu-items li img {
        display: none;
    }
    .ty-menu__submenu .ty-menu__submenu-items .ty-menu__submenu-item .ty-menu__submenu-link {
        padding: 12px 30px 12px 20px;
    }
    .ty-menu__submenu .ty-menu__submenu-items .ty-menu__submenu-item .ty-menu__submenu-link.third-level {
        padding: 12px 30px 12px 40px;
    }
}
/* Mini */
 @media only screen and (max-width: 479px) {
}
```

Comment: It's not that easy because you might need to change the whole menu structure (html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to position the hover menu in position relative, you were on the right way. Add this to your code:

```
.ty-menu__submenu-items{
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      width: 100%;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Here's a working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/alessiozuccotti/e13bkvyb/7/

Comment: Ahh yea that is were i got to however i need it to be the full size of the window not just the UL menu width... thoughts?

Comment: managed to crack it, seems it the menu is centered applies margins to each side, if i remove margin: 0 auto and add width: 100% seems to do full width - within the outer container anyway.

Comment: You know if you can center the menu but have at 100% width?

Comment: @james just add the parents position static and give position: relative to the header, update fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/alessiozuccotti/e13bkvyb/7/

Comment: Ahh thats perfect mate, nice one! thanks for the help.

Comment: @james Happy to have helped you! Good Job! ;)